# Setting user control to listen for updates in underlying class library

Tags: c#, asp.net

OK, so I have a user control which uses values from an underlying business logic class.  I need some way for the user control to listen to the class and fire when certain methods are called / values are updated on the BL class.

At a high level, what would be the best way to do this?  I know I'd need some form of event in the BL class with a listener in my user control but just wondering the best way to go about it if anyone has any suggestions??

Comment: Do you want changes to be shown to the client after the page has been rendered? For example, something along the line of showing a live sports score/ live stock ticker, etc... Otherwise I find it rather strange to have such callback's in asp.net app.

Comment: yes, it's to notify one control of changes made by a different control on the same page, all reliant on the same model data in the Business Layer. Say you have something similar to amazon where you have your main basket where you can increase basket items. You also have a mini basket. When you change item quantities in the main basket I'd want this change also reflected in the mini basket. For this I was hoping to have the mini basket listen for changes in the underlying model in the BL and also have the ability to update itself client side on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class that should be listen to has to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and the usercontrol has to subscribe to it. Let me show you a short simple sample. Here is a class that has a property and notifiy changes to it:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string myProperty;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (myProperty != value)
            {
                myProperty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your usercontrol should subscribe the PropertyChange event and will be notified on every change.

Answer (score 1):

This is what events are for.

[Here's a good tutorial on Events.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Basically you will create an event in your business class:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

And raise the event when something happens (also in your business class):

```
if(MyEvent != null) MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

The parameters to the event will vary based on the type of the event.

In your consumer class, you subscribe to the event like this"

```
MyEvent += new EventHandler(MyMethod);

public void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

// OR

MyEvent += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { };
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, normally the BL objects live server side, whereas your 'user control' will be at the client.
Having changes to BL objects reach connected client is much more involved than just a simple event.
You will need to have your server be able to contact your client. For this you will need to use some technique like long polling or sockets.

*** EDIT *** 
I've used [WebSync](http://frozenmountain.com/websync/) in the past for such needs. This is a comercial product though. You might want to look at SignalR. Here is a great [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SolvingTheShakespeareMillionMonkeysProblemInRealtimeWithParallelismAndSignalR.aspx) from Scott H about it. This is in development, rather new, open source, but I have not used it.

*** EDIT 2 ***
Now I understand what you are looking for. You need to use Ajax requests to handle your shopping cart. From the client (browser) you will need to submit some data to your backend services. When posting data you need to define callback functions for success/failure. You need to refresh your cart in this callback.

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-8), it will give you a good idea of what you need to do to accomplish this

Comment: BL object don't "normally" live on a separate server than a user control in asp.net.  Unless you're calling a webservice, a simple event should suffice.

Comment: I still believe he wants changes in the BL to be reflected at the client. Otherwise when the user control is preparing to render it's data, it would just query the BL objects for their current state. There would be no need to have a callback system in place.

Comment: @santiagoIT - yes, you are right. Say you have something similar to amazon where you have your main basket where you can increase basket items. You also have a mini basket. When you change item quantities in the main basket I'd want this change also reflected in the mini basket. For this I was hoping to have the mini basket listen for changes in the underlying model in the BL and also have the ability to update itself client side on screen.